# Intersection of subvector bundles

Tags: vector-bundles, fibre-bundles

Suppose we have a smooth vector bundle $\pi: E \rightarrow B$ and two sub vector bundles $\pi_1: E_1 \rightarrow B_1$ and $\pi_2: E_2 \rightarrow B_2$ such that 
the bases $B_1$ and $B_2$ are submanifolds of $B$. Now suppose we would like to intersect both subbundles, that is we would like to define 'something like' 
$\pi_{1,2}: E_{12} \rightarrow B_1 \cap B_2$ where:

1.) $B_1 \cap B_2$ is a (smooth) submanifold of $B$.

2.) For each $b \in B_1 \cap B_2$ we define 
$\pi_{1,2}^{-1}(b):= \pi_{1}^{-1}(b) \cap \pi_{2}^{-1}(b)$ as the (standard set theoretic) intersection of the fibers of $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ and 
$E_{12}:=\bigcup_{b \in B_1 \cap B_2}\pi_{1,2}^{-1}(b)$.

3.) The dimension $dim(\pi_{1,2}^{-1}(b))$ is constant for all $b \in B_1 \cap B_2$.

===================================================

Is this a vector bundle?

Is it a sub(vector) bundle of $\pi$?

===================================================

P.S.: I know the discussion here:

[About the intersection of two vector bundles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7926/about-the-intersection-of-two-vector-bundles)

but since it doesn't solve the problem, I think its o.k. to ask my question anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every  vector space $V$ we have a difference map

$$ D: V\oplus V\to V,\;\; D(v_0,v_1)=v_1-v_0$$

whose kernel is the diagonal $\Delta_V\subset  V\oplus V$.  More generally, for vector bundles we have a bundle map 
$$D: E\oplus E\to E$$

whose kernel is the diagonal sub-bundle  $\Delta_E$.  Consider now the restriction $\bar{D}$ of $D$ to the subbundle   $F:=E_1\oplus E_2 \subset E\oplus E$. For any $b\in B$ the kernel of $\bar{D}_b$ can be identified with the subspace $E_1(b)\cap E_2(b)$.    This suggests a more general  problem.

> Suppose that $E,F\to B$ are smooth
>   vector bundles over a compact smooth
>   manifold $B$ and $T: F\to E$ is a
>   smooth bundle morphism such that $\dim
> > \ker T_b$ is independent of  $b$. Then
>   the family of subspaces $ \ker T_b$
>   forms  a  smooth vector bundle.

This is certainly the case. To se this equip  $E$ and $F$ with metrics and observe  that

$$\ker T=\ker \left(T^*T: E\to E\right)$$

so we reduce the problem to    the case when $E=F$ and $T$ is selfadjoint and nonnegative definite. *This is what I will assume in the sequel.*

For  $b\in B$ we denote by $\lambda(b)$ the smallest  nonzero eigenvalue of $T_b$.   The fact that the dimension of $\ker T_b$  **is independent of** $b$ implies that

$$\lambda_0:=\inf_{b\in B} \lambda(b) >0. $$

Use the spectral theorem to represent   the projection  onto $\ker T_b$ as a contour integral along a   circle in the plane centered   at $0$ and of radius $\lambda_0/2$. This proves that this projection  depends smoothly on $b$ and thus solves the above problem.

Comment: nice answer. Unfortunately neither of $B$, $B_1$, $B_2$ nor $B_1 \cap B_2$ is assumed to be compact.  

Comment: I know that in the case of topological vector bundles the kernel of a vector bundle morphism is a vector bundle if the morphism is of constant rank. But I don't know if this holds in the smooth setting,too. I guess together with your beautiful diagonal construction, this will work, right?


Comment: The smoothness comes form the representation of the projection as a contour integral. This integral depends smoothly on parameters.  Note that in your problem  you can assume from the very beginning that $E_1,E_2$ are  defined on $B'=B_1\cap B_2$. Thus you can assume from the very beginning that $B=B_1=B_2$.  Next, compactness is not needed.    All we need is that for any compact $K$ the  number $\inf_{b\in K}\lambda_b$ is positive.


  